# JS: Know how many times have one class a row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a foreach (to make the rows with the columns). Each row have some fields with the class `.hidden-td`. If I have for example 20 rows and each row have 3fields with the class `.hidden-td` I will get with this line `var numcells = $('.hidden-td').length;` 60. And I only need to know how many `.hidden-td` fields I have in the row with class `.placeholder-style`(one specific row).

Which is the correct way to make it with JavaScript?

Comment: $('.hidden-td .placeholder-style').length

Comment: *"I only need to know how many .hidden-td fields I have in the row with class .placeholder-style(one specific row)"* ***Which*** row?

Comment: seems like you lack the basics of css selectors. I suggest you look into them. How to select children depending on their parent

Answer (score 1):

```
var numcells = $('.placeholder-style .hidden-td').length;
```

should work fine

Comment: Do not use size(), been deprecated for ages and removed in version 3

Comment: *"I only need to know how many .hidden-td fields I have in the row with class .placeholder-style (**one specific row**)"* (my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) if you need the number of rows.

```
var count = $('tr:has(".hidden-td")').length
```

or if you are asking how to limit it to only rows with the class than add it to your selector.

```
var count = $('tr.placeholder-style .hidden-td').length
```

or if you are looping:

```
$("tr.placeholder-style").each( function(){
  console.log($(this).find(".hidden-td").length))
})
```

Comment: I need to specify in your code which `<tr>`, must be the `<tr class="placeholder-style">`

Comment: So add the class to the tr so it is  `tr.placeholder-style`. I am unclear what you are asking exactly....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you know in which tr ( specific class ) to look for your td's.

Use the same logic as in CSS when you try to style a td with class`cell` inside a tr with class `row`  `tr.row td.cell { /*styles*/ }`

With that logic change your code to `$('.placeholder-style .hidden-td').length`